# removing text part between 2 symbols

Tags: bash, genome, bcftools

I have this type of text file (also header, starting with ##, but not shown)

```
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO
chr1    69511   rs2691305       A       G       .       PASS    AC=70482;AN=83312;AF=0.846001;popmax=eas;faf95_popmax=0.975176;AC_non_v2_XX=28734;AN_non_v2_XX=33774;AF_non_v2_XX=0.850773;nhomalt_non_v2_XX=13253;AC_non_cancer_fin_XX=1080;AN_non_cancer_fin_XX=1090;AF_non_cancer_fin_XX=0.990826;nhomalt_non_cancer_fin_XX=537;AC_non_neuro_nfe=32992;AN_non_neuro_nfe=34106;AF_non_neuro_nfe=0.967337;nhomalt_non_neuro_nfe=16243;AC_non_neuro_afr_XY=5275;AN_non_neuro_afr_XY=8862;AF_non_neuro_afr_XY=0.595238;nhomalt_non_neuro_afr_XY=1908;AC_non_neuro_nfe_XY=13529;AN_non_neuro_nfe_XY=13954;AF_non_neuro_nfe_XY=0.969543;nhomalt_non_neuro_nfe_XY=6668;AC_controls_and_biobanks_eas_XY=1209;AN_controls_and_biobanks_eas_XY=1210;AF_controls_and_biobanks_eas_XY=0.999174;nhomalt_controls_and_biobanks_eas_XY=604;AC_non_neuro_sas_XX=623;AN_non_neuro_sas_XX=646;AF_non_neuro_sas_XX=0.964396;nhomalt_non_neuro_sas_XX=304;AC_non_v2=53211;AN_non_v2=62346;AF_non_v2=0.853479;nhomalt_non_v2=24615;AC_non_topmed_nfe_XX=4123;AN_non_topmed_nfe_XX=4274;AF_non_topmed_nfe_XX=0.96467;nhomalt_non_topmed_nfe_XX=2022;AC_non_v2_mid=132;AN_non_v2_mid=146;AF_non_v2_mid=0.90411;nhomalt_non_v2_mid=63;AC_non_topmed_sas=2561;AN_non_topmed_sas=2620;AF_non_topmed_sas=0.977481;nhomalt_non_topmed_sas=1262;AC_non_cancer_eas_XX=1882;AN_non_cancer_eas_XX=1882;AF_non_cancer_eas_XX=1;nhomalt_non_cancer_eas_XX=941;AC_amr_XY=3590;AN_amr_XY=3984;AF_amr_XY=0.901104;nhomalt_amr_XY=1703;AC_non_v2_nfe_XX=16770;AN_non_v2_nfe_XX=17374;AF_non_v2_nfe_XX=0.965235;nhomalt_non_v2_nfe_XX=8244;AC_controls_and_biobanks_XY=8601;AN_controls_and_biobanks_XY=10004;AF_controls_and_biobanks_XY=0.859756;nhomalt_controls_and_biobanks_XY=3996;AC_non_neuro_asj_XY=704;AN_non_neuro_asj_XY=712;AF_non_neuro_asj_XY=0.988764;nhomalt_non_neuro_asj_XY=349;AC_oth=909;AN_oth=1054;AF_oth=0.862429;nhomalt_oth=423;AC_non_topmed_mid_XY=54;AN_non_topmed_mid_XY=62;AF_non_topmed_mid_XY=0.870968;nhomalt_non_topmed_mid_XY=25;AC_non_cancer_asj_XX=717;AN_non_cancer_asj_XX=738;AF_non_cancer_asj_XX=0.971545;nhomalt_non_cancer_asj_XX=355;AC_sas_XY=1951;AN_sas_XY=1988;AF_sas_XY=0.981388;nhomalt_sas_XY=964;AC_non_neuro_fin=2299;AN_non_neuro_fin=2320;AF_non_neuro_fin=0.990948;nhomalt_non_neuro_fin=1143;AC_non_topmed_amr_XY=3136;AN_non_topmed_amr_XY=3472;AF_non_topmed_amr_XY=0.903226;nhomalt_non_topmed_amr_XY=1485;AC_non_neuro_XX=33979;AN_non_neuro_XX=39912;AF_non_neuro_XX=0.851348;nhomalt_non_neuro_XX=15705;AC_fin_XX=1080;AN_fin_XX=1090;AF_fin_XX=0.990826;nhomalt_fin_XX=537;AC_controls_and_biobanks_asj_XX=33;AN_controls_and_biobanks_asj_XX=36;AF_controls_and_biobanks_asj_XX=0.916667;nhomalt_controls_and_biobanks_asj_XX=16;AC_non_v2_raw=65347;AN_non_v2_raw=75212;AF_non_v2_raw=0.868837;nhomalt_non_v2_raw=30604;AC_non_v2_asj=1346;AN_non_v2_asj=1376;AF_non_v2_asj=0.978198;nhomalt_non_v2_asj=667;AC_nfe_XX=20155;AN_nfe_XX=20870;AF_nfe_XX=0.96574;nhomalt_nfe_XX=9913;AC_controls_and_biobanks_raw=19299;AN_controls_and_biobanks_raw=22446;AF_controls_and_biobanks_raw=0.859797;nhomalt_controls_and_biobanks_raw=9003;AC_controls_and_biobanks_ami=38;AN_controls_and_biobanks_ami=38;AF_controls_and_biobanks_ami=1;nhomalt_controls_and_biobanks_ami=19;AC_non_topmed_eas=3105;AN_non_topmed_eas=3106;AF_non_topmed_eas=0.999678;nhomalt_non_topmed_eas=1552;AC_non_v2_amr=5789;AN_non_v2_amr=6480;AF_non_v2_amr=0.893364;nhomalt_non_v2_amr=2735;AC_non_neuro_sas=2572;AN_non_neuro_sas=2632;AF_non_neuro_sas=0.977204;nhomalt_non_neuro_sas=1267;AC_non_cancer_fin_XY=2645;AN_non_cancer_fin_XY=2670;AF_non_cancer_fin_XY=0.990637;nhomalt_non_cancer_fin_XY=1315;AC_non_cancer_nfe_XY=13444;AN_non_cancer_nfe_XY=13872;AF_non_cancer_nfe_XY=0.969146;nhomalt_non_cancer_nfe_XY=6624;AC_non_v2_oth=809;AN_non_v2_oth=946;AF_non_v2_oth=0.85518;nhomalt_non_v2_oth=376;AC_ami=491;AN_ami=492;AF_ami=0.997967;nhomalt_ami=245;AC_non_cancer_XY=32353;AN_non_cancer_XY=38240;AF_non_cancer_XY=0.846051;nhomalt_non_cancer_XY=14919;AC_non_v2_sas=1960;AN_non_v2_sas=2004;AF_non_v2_sas=0.978044;nhomalt_non_v2_sas=966;AC_non_topmed_afr_XX=4111;AN_non_topmed_afr_XX=7054;AF_non_topmed_afr_XX=0.58279;nhomalt_non_topmed_afr_XX=1412;AC_sas=2574;AN_sas=2634;AF_sas=0.977221;nhomalt_sas=1268;AC_non_neuro_nfe_XX=19463;AN_non_neuro_nfe_XX=20152;AF_non_neuro_nfe_XX=0.96581;nhomalt_non_neuro_nfe_XX=9575;AC_non_topmed_ami_XX=30;AN_non_topmed_ami_XX=30;AF_non_topmed_ami_XX=1;nhomalt_non_topmed_ami_XX=15;AC_ami_XY=260;AN_ami_XY=260;AF_ami_XY=1;nhomalt_ami_XY=130;AC_oth_XX=454;AN_oth_XX=526;AF_oth_XX=0.863118;nhomalt_oth_XX=212;AC_non_cancer_eas=4205;AN_non_cancer_eas=4206;AF_non_cancer_eas=0.999762;nhomalt_non_cancer_eas=2102;AC_non_topmed_XY=20145;AN_non_topmed_XY=24026;AF_non_topmed_XY=0.838467;nhomalt_non_topmed_XY=9220;AC_non_v2_ami=491;AN_non_v2_ami=492;AF_non_v2_ami=0.997967;nhomalt_non_v2_ami=245;AC_non_neuro=64083;AN_non_neuro=74560;AF_non_neuro=0.859482;nhomalt_non_neuro=29803;AC_amr_XX=2930;AN_amr_XX=3300;AF_amr_XX=0.887879;nhomalt_amr_XX=1379;AC_controls_and_biobanks_nfe_XY=1772;AN_controls_and_biobanks_nfe_XY=1828;AF_controls_and_biobanks_nfe_XY=0.969365;nhomalt_controls_and_biobanks_nfe_XY=875;AC_controls_and_biobanks_eas=2117;AN_controls_and_biobanks_eas=2118;AF_controls_and_biobanks_eas=0.999528;nhomalt_controls_and_biobanks_eas=1058;AC_XX=36762;AN_XX=43622;AF_XX=0.84274;nhomalt_XX=16901;AC_non_cancer_oth_XY=420;AN_non_cancer_oth_XY=492;AF_non_cancer_oth_XY=0.853659;nhomalt_non_cancer_oth_XY=194;AC_non_v2_XY=24477;AN_non_v2_XY=28572;AF_non_v2_XY=0.856678;nhomalt_non_v2_XY=11362;AC_non_topmed_amr_XX=2235;AN_non_topmed_amr_XX=2556;AF_non_topmed_amr_XX=0.874413;nhomalt_non_topmed_amr_XX=1042;AC_fin=3725;AN_fin=3760;AF_fin=0.990691;nhomalt_fin=1852;AC_controls_and_biobanks_nfe_XX=1554;AN_controls_and_biobanks_nfe_XX=1606;AF_controls_and_biobanks_nfe_XX=0.967621;nhomalt_controls_and_biobanks_nfe_XX=764;AC_controls_and_biobanks_afr=3114;AN_controls_and_biobanks_afr=5404;AF_controls_and_biobanks_afr=0.57624;nhomalt_controls_and_biobanks_afr=1081;AC_asj_XX=785;AN_asj_XX=808;AF_asj_XX=0.971535;nhomalt_asj_XX=389;AC_non_topmed_mid=121;AN_non_topmed_mid=134;AF_non_topmed_mid=0.902985;nhomalt_non_topmed_mid=57;AC_non_cancer_sas_XY=1937;AN_non_cancer_sas_XY=1974;AF_non_cancer_sas_XY=0.981256;nhomalt_non_cancer_sas_XY=957;AC_sas_XX=623;AN_sas_XX=646;AF_sas_XX=0.964396;nhomalt_sas_XX=304;AC_non_topmed=33968;AN_non_topmed=41354;AF_non_topmed=0.821396;nhomalt_non_topmed=15349;AC_non_v2_oth_XX=424;AN_non_v2_oth_XX=494;AF_non_v2_oth_XX=0.8583;nhomalt_non_v2_oth_XX=198;AC_non_neuro_ami_XY=258;AN_non_neuro_ami_XY=258;AF_non_neuro_ami_XY=1;nhomalt_non_neuro_ami_XY=129;AC_controls_and_biobanks_afr_XY=1519;AN_controls_and_biobanks_afr_XY=2640;AF_controls_and_biobanks_afr_XY=0.575379;nhomalt_controls_and_biobanks_afr_XY=524;AC_controls_and_biobanks_amr_XX=1171;AN_controls_and_biobanks_amr_XX=1346;AF_controls_and_biobanks_amr_XX=0.869985;nhomalt_controls_and_biobanks_amr_XX=544;AC_non_topmed_amr=5371;AN_non_topmed_amr=6028;AF_non_topmed_amr=0.891009;nhomalt_non_topmed_amr=2527;AC_controls_and_biobanks_sas_XX=483;AN_controls_and_biobanks_sas_XX=502;AF_controls_and_biobanks_sas_XX=0.962151;nhomalt_controls_and_biobanks_sas_XX=235;AC_controls_and_biobanks_amr=2207;AN_controls_and_biobanks_amr=2526;AF_controls_and_biobanks_amr=0.873713;nhomalt_controls_and_biobanks_amr=1024;AC_non_neuro_fin_XX=308;AN_non_neuro_fin_XX=310;AF_non_neuro_fin_XX=0.993548;nhomalt_non_neuro_fin_XX=153;AC_non_cancer_raw=83987;AN_non_cancer_raw=97764;AF_non_cancer_raw=0.859079;nhomalt_non_cancer_raw=39150;AC_non_neuro_mid=133;AN_non_neuro_mid=148;AF_non_neuro_mid=0.898649;nhomalt_non_neuro_mid=63;AC_non_v2_asj_XY=633;AN_non_v2_asj_XY=640;AF_non_v2_asj_XY=0.989063;nhomalt_non_v2_asj_XY=314;AC_non_v2_afr=10781;AN_non_v2_afr=18036;AF_non_v2_afr=0.597749;nhomalt_non_v2_afr=3838;AC_non_neuro_fin_XY=1991;AN_non_neuro_fin_XY=2010;AF_non_neuro_fin_XY=0.990547;nhomalt_non_neuro_fin_XY=990;AC_non_cancer_afr=15441;AN_non_cancer_afr=25954;AF_non_cancer_afr=0.594937;nhomalt_non_cancer_afr=5504;AC_non_topmed_sas_XY=1938;AN_non_topmed_sas_XY=1974;AF_non_topmed_sas_XY=0.981763;nhomalt_non_topmed_sas_XY=958;AC_mid_XY=58;AN_mid_XY=66;AF_mid_XY=0.878788;nhomalt_mid_XY=27;AC_non_v2_oth_XY=385;AN_non_v2_oth_XY=452;AF_non_v2_oth_XY=0.85177;nhomalt_non_v2_oth_XY=178;AC_controls_and_biobanks_fin=1764;AN_controls_and_biobanks_fin=1780;AF_controls_and_biobanks_fin=0.991011;nhomalt_controls_and_biobanks_fin=878;AC_non_neuro_eas_XY=2447;AN_non_neuro_eas_XY=2448;AF_non_neuro_eas_XY=0.999592;nhomalt_non_neuro_eas_XY=1223;AC_non_topmed_eas_XX=1190;AN_non_topmed_eas_XX=1190;AF_non_topmed_eas_XX=1;nhomalt_non_topmed_eas_XX=595;AC_non_v2_afr_XX=5981;AN_non_v2_afr_XX=9968;AF_non_v2_afr_XX=0.60002;nhomalt_non_v2_afr_XX=2121;AC_non_neuro_amr_XX=2854;AN_non_neuro_amr_XX=3216;AF_non_neuro_amr_XX=0.887438;nhomalt_non_neuro_amr_XX=1342;AC_non_cancer_ami=491;AN_non_cancer_ami=492;AF_non_cancer_ami=0.997967;nhomalt_non_cancer_ami=245;AC_XY=33720;AN_XY=39690;AF_XY=0.849584;nhomalt_XY=15588;AC_non_topmed_asj_XX=117;AN_non_topmed_asj_XX=120;AF_non_topmed_asj_XX=0.975;nhomalt_non_topmed_asj_XX=58;AC_non_topmed_eas_XY=1915;AN_non_topmed_eas_XY=1916;AF_non_topmed_eas_XY=0.999478;nhomalt_non_topmed_eas_XY=957;AC_non_v2_eas_XY=1189;AN_non_v2_eas_XY=1190;AF_non_v2_eas_XY=0.99916;nhomalt_non_v2_eas_XY=594;AC_eas=4423;AN_eas=4424;AF_eas=0.999774;nhomalt_eas=2211;AC_asj_XY=712;AN_asj_XY=722;AF_asj_XY=0.98615;nhomalt_asj_XY=353;AC_non_v2_eas_XX=1096;AN_non_v2_eas_XX=1096;AF_non_v2_eas_XX=1;nhomalt_non_v2_eas_XX=548;AC_controls_and_biobanks_mid_XY=47;AN_controls_and_biobanks_mid_XY=52;AF_controls_and_biobanks_mid_XY=0.903846;nhomalt_controls_and_biobanks_mid_XY=22;AC_fin_XY=2645;AN_fin_XY=2670;AF_fin_XY=0.990637;nhomalt_fin_XY=1315;AC_non_topmed_nfe=9566;AN_non_topmed_nfe=9888;AF_non_topmed_nfe=0.967435;nhomalt_non_topmed_nfe=4705;AC_amr=6520;AN_amr=7284;AF_amr=0.895113;nhomalt_amr=3082;AC_non_neuro_ami=479;AN_non_neuro_ami=480;AF_non_neuro_ami=0.997917;nhomalt_non_neuro_ami=239;AC_non_cancer_nfe_XX=19459;AN_non_cancer_nfe_XX=20160;AF_non_cancer_nfe_XX=0.965228;nhomalt_non_cancer_nfe_XX=9567;AC_non_cancer_mid=130;AN_non_cancer_mid=142;AF_non_cancer_mid=0.915493;nhomalt_non_cancer_mid=62;AC_non_v2_mid_XY=55;AN_non_v2_mid_XY=62;AF_non_v2_mid_XY=0.887097;nhomalt_non_v2_mid_XY=26;AC_controls_and_biobanks_amr_XY=1036;AN_controls_and_biobanks_amr_XY=1180;AF_controls_and_biobanks_amr_XY=0.877966;nhomalt_controls_and_biobanks_amr_XY=480;AC_non_cancer_ami_XY=260;AN_non_cancer_ami_XY=260;AF_non_cancer_ami_XY=1;nhomalt_non_cancer_ami_XY=130;AC_non_neuro_asj_XX=773;AN_non_neuro_asj_XX=796;AF_non_neuro_asj_XX=0.971106;nhomalt_non_neuro_asj_XX=383;AC_afr=15571;AN_afr=26178;AF_afr=0.594812;nhomalt_afr=5552;AC_non_v2_sas_XX=387;AN_non_v2_sas_XX=402;AF_non_v2_sas_XX=0.962687;nhomalt_non_v2_sas_XX=189;AC_non_neuro_afr_XX=7242;AN_non_neuro_afr_XX=11996;AF_non_neuro_afr_XX=0.603701;nhomalt_non_neuro_afr_XX=2607;AC_non_cancer_sas=2548;AN_non_cancer_sas=2608;AF_non_cancer_sas=0.976994;nhomalt_non_cancer_sas=1255;AC_non_topmed_fin=3675;AN_non_topmed_fin=3710;AF_non_topmed_fin=0.990566;nhomalt_non_topmed_fin=1827;AC_non_cancer_asj_XY=692;AN_non_cancer_asj_XY=702;AF_non_cancer_asj_XY=0.985755;nhomalt_non_cancer_asj_XY=343;AC_non_cancer_mid_XY=55;AN_non_cancer_mid_XY=60;AF_non_cancer_mid_XY=0.916667;nhomalt_non_cancer_mid_XY=26;AC_raw=86570;AN_raw=100496;AF_raw=0.861427;nhomalt_raw=40413;AC_non_topmed_XX=13823;AN_non_topmed_XX=17328;AF_non_topmed_XX=0.797726;nhomalt_non_topmed_XX=6129;AC_ami_XX=231;AN_ami_XX=232;AF_ami_XX=0.99569;nhomalt_ami_XX=115;AC_eas_XY=2447;
```

I need to remove all parts between symbols ;;, that contain "_XX" in the end.

So that output is

```
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO
    chr1    69511   rs2691305       A       G       .       PASS    AC=70482;AN=83312;AF=0.846001;popmax=eas;faf95_popmax=0.975176;AC_non_neuro_nfe=32992;AN_non_neuro_nfe=34106;AF_non_neuro_nfe=0.967337;nhomalt_non_neuro_nfe=16243;AC_non_neuro_afr_XY=5275;AN_non_neuro_afr_XY=8862;AF_non_neuro_afr_XY=0.595238;nhomalt_non_neuro_afr_XY=1908;AC_non_neuro_nfe_XY=13529;AN_non_neuro_nfe_XY=13954;
```

etc, etc

I tried to use bcftools

```
bcftools query -f '%CHROM\t%POS\t%ID\t%REF\t%ALT\t%QUAL\t%FILTER\t%INFO/AC";"%INFO/AN";"%INFO/AF";"%INFO/popmax";"%INFO/AC_controls_and_biobanks_nfe_XY";"%INFO/AN_controls_and_biobanks_nfe_XY";"%INFO/AF_controls_and_biobanks_nfe_XY
```

But it removes population names, which is also needed.

To explain better: remove all the characters (they are changing integers, not constant symbols) between ; , that ends with _XX. All the file structure should be saved, and no additional tabs or new lines included.
Is there some way to do it in bash?
I think that

```
 `sed 's/_XX//'` should be implemented somehow.
```

I tried this:

```
s/[^ ]*_XX[^ ]*//ig

sed -e 's/[^ ]*_XX[^ ]*//ig'


 sed 's/^_XX//'
```

but no results.

Thank you!

Comment: please update the question with **a)** a smaller set of input (you don't need a 12KB string of text to demonstrate the input) and **b)** the desired output that matches the given input (eg, current desired output is missing the last item from the input, namely, `AC_eas_XY=2447` ... why is this item missing from your desired output since it does not contain the string `_XX`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this is probably something that you're looking for:

```
sed -E 's/([a-zA-Z0-9]+_)+XX=[.0-9]+;//g' input.txt
```

To remove in-place:

```
sed -Ei 's/([a-zA-Z0-9]+_)+XX=[.0-9]+;//g' input.txt
```

To remove in-place and create a backup:

```
sed -Ei.bak 's/([a-zA-Z0-9]+_)+XX=[.0-9]+;//g' input.txt
```